# Sql FOR XML PATH returns Incorrect Syntax near 'PATH'

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml, for-xml-path

This seems like this should be really simple, but I don't see what's wrong.

```
DECLARE @companies TABLE(
    [companyId] SMALLINT        
)

INSERT INTO @companies
   SELECT TOP 3 tc.CompanyID AS 'companyId'
   FROM dbo.tblCompanies tc

SELECT * 
FROM @companies c
```

This query returns this data.

```
companyId
---------
  1
  2
  3
```

When I try to use FOR XML, these work:

```
-- this works
SELECT  companyId
FROM @companies [company]
FOR XML AUTO

-- this works
SELECT  companyId
FROM @companies [company]
FOR XML RAW
```

But this returns an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'PATH'

and I can't figure out why.

```
-- why doesn't this work?
SELECT companyId
FROM @companies
FOR XML PATH('company')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm missing something, because I don't get an error. What is `SELECT @@VERSION;`?

Answer (score 2):

Geez, I was connecting to a server at work that was Sql Server 2000.  That's why it wasn't working.  Wasn't supported.

Comment: Well, DUH ! :-) A classic "PICNIC" problem - problem in chair, not in computer :-)

Comment: In a heterogeneous environment it is not immediately obvious what version of SQL I am connected to. I was grateful for this hint. IDTTWAPITC (I don't think there was a problem in the chair).